# Force non-deduced context - type_identity etc

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction, type-deduction

I'm trying to make a template which deduces a type associated with one template parameter, while treating other types in a non-deduced context.  A minimal example is provided below.  I can do what I'm looking for using two deduction contexts, but can it be done in one?  I thought I'd try using something like `type_identity`, but I'm not having any luck.

Live example: https://onlinegdb.com/By0iDOM-P

```
template<size_t... Idx, size_t s>
void foo(index_sequence<Idx..., s>) {
    cout << s << endl;
}

template<typename T>
struct TypeIdentity {
    using Type = T;
};

template<typename T>
using Identity = typename TypeIdentity<T>::Type;

template<typename... Idx, size_t s>
void bar(index_sequence<Identity<Idx>{}..., s>) {
    cout << s << endl;
}

template<size_t s>
void baz(index_sequence<0, s>) {
    cout << s << endl;
}

template<size_t... Idx>
struct Qux {
    template<size_t s>
    static void qux(index_sequence<Idx..., s>) {
        cout << s << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo<0>(make_index_sequence<2>{}); // couldn't deduce template parameter ‘s’
    bar<integral_constant<size_t, 0>>(make_index_sequence<2>{}); // couldn't deduce template parameter ‘s’
    baz(make_index_sequence<2>{});
    Qux<0>::template qux(make_index_sequence<2>{});

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The problem is that `Idx...` pack is too greedy to leave anything for `s`. You can use `s, Idx...` to get the first value, but you can't use `Idx..., s` to get the last one. `TypeIdentity` won't help you to do that and you need some other tricks.

For example, unpacking into an array (C++14):

```
template<std::size_t first, std::size_t... rest>
void foo(std::index_sequence<first, rest...>) {
    const std::size_t indices[]{first, rest...};
    const std::size_t last = indices[sizeof...(rest)];

    std::cout << last << std::endl;
}
```

or using a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) with a [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) (C++17):

```
template<std::size_t first, std::size_t... rest>
void foo(index_sequence<first, rest...>) {
    const std::size_t last = (first, ..., rest);
    std::cout << last << std::endl;
}
```

I isolated `first` to make sure that the whole pack `first, rest...` is never empty.

Comment: Thanks, two deduction contexts, it is!